# Unable to clone Yocto Poky

Tags: ubuntu, yocto

I am unable to clone poky, it is failing with connection timeout error:

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
Cloning into 'poky'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.yoctoproject.org:
git.yoctoproject.org[0: 198.145.29.87]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

On website you have other options to clone it's probably first one don't work, please try with this option.

```
git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend is to simply update the list of root CA known to the system as show below.

## update CA certificates

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y
sudo update-ca-certificates

This may help if you are dealing with a system that has not been updated for a long time, but of course won’t resolve an issue with private certs.

Answer (score 0):

there has been always issues with git on yocto.org, but the mirrors are available on github. so if no work around works, simply use github for poky and the link is https://github.com/yoctoproject/poky